# How can i implement a custom dialog?

Tags: flutter, dart, customdialog

Hello I'm working on an language application and when user clicks on a word, i want to show a custom dialog like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj8k3.png)

Comment: You want to create exactly same widget or you already have the widget and don't know how to show it?

Comment: İ want to create it but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `showDialog`, inside the builder you usually return an instance of `AlertDialog`. The content of `AlertDialog` can be any widget. Use your custom widget inside `AlertDialog` and you are set.

```
showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Dialog Title'),
      content: MyCustomDialogWidget(),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering me but how to make this widget take the custom shape ?

Comment: You image looks like a chat bubble. Why don't you look at the Chat Bubble Package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble)?

Comment: Ok thank you i'll try this one.

Answer (score 0):

better use Dialog widget than AlertDialog

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
     Dialog(
      child: Container(Text("hello")));
```

Comment: Precisely. The child can be the custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it helpful to you.use [**`flutter_custom_clippers`**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) package for your design add this package in your `pubspec.yaml` file, import below package in your code file

```
import 'package:flutter_custom_clippers/flutter_custom_clippers.dart';
```

your alert function:

```
customAlert() {
 showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ClipPath(
          clipper: MessageClipper(),
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            height: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(16.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Add Your Text Here",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
 );
}
```

Your Widget:

```
     TextButton(
        child: Text('Alert'),
        onPressed: () =>
            customAlert(),  
      ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Can i customize it or it's a final result?

Comment: try this answer, if your problem has been solved so accept my answer.